# Power On Tracking Integrated Circuit, ON Time Odometer

Tags: power-supply, rtc, non-volatile-memory

How would I realize a I2C/SPI device capable of tracking how long power has been applied over the lifetime of the device?

Ideally this would be a 8 pin (or less) SMT part costing around a couple dollars. It would be non-volatile (obviously), read-only to external devices and track hours ON through daily power cycling. I'm imagining something like a car odometer except for tracking how many total hours the part has been powered on.

Comment: Recommending products is against the rules here but I can tell you what you should be looking for when you're scouting out these devices. You're looking for something that allows you look at particular status registers. In these status registers, you could look for something that keeps track of what you're looking for. Though, quite frankly, I don't know any devices on the top of my head that keeps track of how long it's been powered on.

Comment: re-phrased it as "how do I realize...", now it's an engineering question, yay!

Comment: Google "elapsed time ic".  That got me to a class of parts that will do what you want.  I do not know what their prices are.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question (and thanks to SteveSh for providing the appropriate search term) Maxim Semi makes just the device I was looking for (DS1682). Thanks to those of you who answered!

Comment: Glad you found the info you wanted.  Stack Exchange frowns on us making specific product recommendations, so I had to dance around the answer.

Answer (score 0):

"A couple of dollars" is a pretty generous budget here: sounds like you'd simply want to use a cheap microcontroller.

If a microcontroller's internal RC clock (which often is ±5 %) isn't sufficient for you, you'd add an external oscillator.

Read-only can be realized with most microcontrollers: They usually have some way of configuring the device so that it can't be re-programmed anymore.

Take the [CY8C4013SXI-410](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/cypress-semiconductor-corp/CY8C4013SXI-410/2015-CY8C4013SXI-410-ND/9771769) as an example: Currently, it costs less than 30ct; it has an internal oscillator, trimmed to ±2%, and hence needs no external components to work as "on-time counter"; ok, maybe a 100 nF decoupling capacitor would be good, but it can probably even be shared between the two supply pins of the its SOIC-8 variant. It's also available in an even smaller 16-QFN package.

The flash it has is specified for 10⁵ erase cycles (that's realistic for most flash memory, by the way). That means we can't just update a stored value every second, because then the lifetime of the device would be very short.

So, either you get smart about wear leveling (not that hard, actually, I'd do it for the kicks alone if I were you): Build a brownout detector, and only write to Flash when your device is losing power; without any wear leveling, that would ensure working for 10⁵ power cycles.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQRujX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With a minimal amount of wear leveling, you can make this work for millions of updates; that might even be sufficient to not require any brownout detection (i.e. no need for D1, R1, R2, C3, and C1 can definitely be chosen smaller).

A trivial wear-level algorithm would simply be:

1. on device programming, initialize the flash memory not used by program code to 0. Lock the programming, so that the chip memory cannot be externally modified anymore.
2. At firmware start, read linearly from the first value in the flash memory. Stop when you find a 0-value, or when the next value is smaller than the last you've read. Safe the location of that value in RAM or a CPU register. This is where you'll be writing your next value.
3. When you need to write a value, replace the value at the address you determined in your previous step.

That way, you can extend your life time by a factor (number of flash rows).

---

Alternatively, there's microcontrollers with what is called "FRAM". These have higher write cycle count than flash memory, but are slightly more expensive. Also, I know of none in a 8-pin package, but my guess is you're not worried about the number of unused pins in your design, but size, and 24-pad QFN is not really large compared to 8-SOIC or 16-QFN.

Comment: Thank you Marcus for your detailed and well thought out answer.